# Dynamically change textbox to multiline

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am working on a Firefox extension. I have a simple single-line textbox. When a user pastes in text, I want to detect if the text has newlines and if it does, I want to expand the textbox into a multiline textbox.

I have

```
<textbox id="textbox" rows="5" wrap="off" newlines="pasteintact" oninput="adjustTextbox(this)" flex="1"/>
```

and on the JS side, I have

```
adjustTextbox(txtBox) {
  if(!txtBox.getAttribute('multiline') && txtBox.value.match(/[\r\n]/)) {
    txtBox.setAttribute('multiline', true);
  }
}
```

The problem is that, while the textbox does get converted to a 5 row multiline textbox, the value that is pasted in is lost and the textbox is blank. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you aren't doing anything wrong, the value is expected to be cleared when you switch from single-line to multi-line. Long answer: the `<textbox>` element doesn't actually hold the value itself, it rather contains an anonymous `<html:input type="text>`. When you add the `multiline` attribute a different XBL binding applies to the element and that anonymous text field is replaced by `<html:textarea>`. Obviously, the value gets lost in the process.

You could try to save the value and to restore it after you add the `multiline` attribute. The problem is that it is hard to tell when the binding actually applies, there is a delay that is not really predictable. So the better solution would be to have both a single-line and a multi-line text box in your document and make sure that one of them is always collapsed:

```xml
<textbox id="textbox" newlines="pasteintact" oninput="adjustTextbox(this)" flex="1"/>
<textbox id="textbox2" collapsed="true" multiline="true" rows="5" wrap="off" flex="1"/>
```

And on the JavaScript side:

```js
function adjustTextbox(txtBox) {
  if(!txtBox.getAttribute('multiline') && txtBox.value.match(/[\r\n]/)) {
    var txtBox2 = document.getElementById("textbox2");
    txtBox2.value = txtBox.value;
    txtBox.collapsed = true;
    txtBox2.collapsed = false;
  }
}
```